# Where to find xchat for debian stretch

Tags: debian, irc, xchat

It seems that the package `xchat` is not available in the stretch repository, all I can find is `xchat-gnome`. Can someone tell me if it was removed and if so, why?

I'm using mate desktop by the way.

My `sources.list`

```
deb http://ftp.de.debian.org/debian/ stretch non-free contrib main  
deb-src http://ftp.de.debian.org/debian/ stretch non-free contrib main  

deb http://security.debian.org/ stretch/updates non-free contrib main  
deb-src http://security.debian.org/ stretch/updates non-free contrib main  

deb http://ftp.de.debian.org/debian/ stretch-updates non-free contrib main  
deb-src http://ftp.de.debian.org/debian/ stretch-updates non-free contrib main
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Since XChat has not received software updates since 2013 (https://sourceforge.net/p/xchat/svn/HEAD/tree/)

I ended up using the [`hexchat`](https://hexchat.github.io/) package.

Comment: Hopefully using the [`hexchat`](https://tracker.debian.org/hexchat) package available in Debian ;-).

Answer (score 2):

Neither `xchat` nor `xchat-gnome` is in the stretch repository since it became stable. But switching to `hexchat` is quite easy since the config files didn't change much. Just copy the lines you need from `.xchat2/servlist.conf` to `.config/hexchat/servlist.conf` (using `meld` for example). If you configured something else, check the other files as well. When you copy the history from the `scrollback` directory, watch out for changed names (e.g. `FreeNode` was renamed to `freenode`).